# How to change gamplay to gamepad on Blacklist Wii U

Tags: wii-u, splinter-cell-blacklist

How can you go from TV play to gamepad play in Blacklist on the Wii U? You can change it easily at the beginning of the game, by tapping the gamepad, but it isn't that easy when the tv is turned off, or suddenly occupied by your evil twin sister. I know it is in the menu somewhere, but how to do this blindly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the '+'-button to open up the menu, then 'up' once on the d-pad to select the 'Play on gamepad' option. Then press twice 'A' to select and confirm.